# How do I find line integrals?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex

For example, how can I calculate

$$\int_{\left | z \right |=1}\frac{dz}{z}$$

I know that the answer is $2\pi i$ but how do I do it using *Mathematica*?

Comment: Parametrize the range of integration. Then make sure you properly rewrite dz using the chain rule. (@Nasser gave a response with explicit detail in case this is not clear.)

Answer (score 15):

If you want to calculate this integral with *Mathematica* use beautiful (and very powerful!)$\;$ [Cauchy Integral Formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CauchyIntegralFormula.html) implying an adequate theorem of [Complex Residue](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ComplexResidue.html). Thus we have 
$$\int_{\left | z \right |=1}\frac{dz}{z}= 2\pi i\; Res_{z_{0}=0} f$$ 
where $f(z)=\frac{1}{z}$.

We can find the residue at $z_0=0$ of $f(z)$ in *Mathematica* with `Residue`:

```
Residue[1/z, {z, 0}]
```

> ```
> 1
> ```

therefore:

$$\int_{\left | z \right |=1}\frac{dz}{z}= 2\pi i$$

Answer (score 10):

```
z = Exp[I t];
dz = D[z, t];
Integrate[(1/z) dz, {t, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The idea is to convert it to complex contour integration.

Comment: This is incorrect, `dt` is  "infinitesimal" while `D[z[t],t]` is not (in `dt = D[z[t], t]`), etc...

Comment: @Artes, so I assume you do not want the first way of expression it? i.e. use explicit function? Will remove the function, and keep the expression. no problem.

Comment: You could write `dz = D[z, t] dt` but you musn't write `dz = D[z, t]`. Next `Integrate[(1/z) dz, {t, 0, 2 Pi}]` doesn't make sense.

Comment: Now, your approach is more appropriate, unfortunately using this symbol `dz` it seems to be a differential while it seems you are using it in a different context. You haven't demonstrated seamlessly why you change $\frac{dz}{z}$ to another function using the same symbols.