# How would you calculate a contour integral?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex

How would you be able to calculate a contour integral of `1/(((z-1)^2)*(z-i))` over the contour `|z-1| = 1`?  Not sure how to type that in :/

Comment: There are at least a few answers at MSE discussing how to deal with contour integrals e.g.  [Paths integrals in the complex plane](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/36961/paths-integrals-in-the-complex-plane/36962#36962) or [How do I find line integrals?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31017/how-do-i-find-line-integrals/31021#31021) or [How to calculate contour integrals with Mathematica?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34073/how-to-calculate-contour-integrals-with-mathematica/34090#34090).

Comment: If you had a specific problem with this integral, try to expose it clearly, however I find your question simply a duplicate of the one in the first link.

Comment: its not a duplicate as my integral is shifted to the right

Answer (score 8):

With

```
f[z_] := 1/((z - 1)^2*(z - I))
```

the contour integral around a circle centered at `z == 1` can be parameterized by arc length around the circle.

```
Integrate[(f[z] /. z -> 1 + Cos[t] + I Sin[t]) D[1 + Cos[t] + I Sin[t], t],
    {t, 0, 2 Pi}]   
(* π *)
```

which, of course, is equal to the residue at `z == 1`, multiplied by `2 π I`.  (The pole at `z == I` is outside the contour and so does not contribute to the integral.)

Alternatively, the integral can be performed over a region.

```
reg = ParametricRegion[{1 + Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {{t, 0, 2 Pi}}];
Integrate[(f[z] /. z -> x + I y) (-y + I (x - 1)), {x, y} ∈ reg]
```

which gives the same result.  `(-y + I (x - 1))` is the equivalent of `D[1 + Cos[t] + I Sin[t], t]`.

Answer (score 2):

Let me know if your answer matches with the one using

```
f[z_] := 1/((z - 1)^2*(z - I))

Int[a_] := 2*Pi*I*Total[(Residue[f[z], {z, #1}] & ) /@ {0, a}]
```

So for `a=1`, you get `Pi`

Comment: didn't do anything :/

Comment: What is your expected answer @Alex

Comment: well I did my integral by hand and just wanted to confirm my answer, I got pi when computing my integral

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice the a part.  Thank you!!  Just wanted to confirm

Comment: I would give you an up vote but I need to be 15 rep to do that :c

Comment: 1 more thing, what is the significance of using 1 for a?

Comment: @Alex it got to do with the |z-1|=1 boundary

Comment: Okay,well thanks again thils