# Having problems integrating a meromorphic function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, complex

I've tried to calculate the integral

[image: integral of z^2/(Exp[z] - 1)^2 around the 3pi complex circle.]

And I got the result $16i \pi ^3$.

I wanted to check my calculation, so I ran this code in Mathematica:

```
With[{z = 3 π Exp[I th]}, NIntegrate[z^2/(Exp[z] - 1)^2, {th, 0, 2 π}]]
```

which gave me the answer $18.8496$ (Which is $6\pi$).

I couldn't find any mistakes in my calculation, so I gave Wolfram the following code which calculates the integral with the residue theorem and  with poles at $\pm 2\pi i$

```
N[2 π I 
   (Residue[z^2/(Exp[z] - 1)^2, {z, 2 Pi I}] + 
    Residue[z^2/(Exp[z] - 1)^2, {z, -2 Pi I}])]
```

And that code gave me $0. + 496.1 i$, which is the numerical representation of my result for the integral.

Does someone know why do the straight forward approach didn't work?

Comment: Isn't there a pole at $z = 0$?

Comment: The pole at $z=0$ isn't really a pole - It's a removable singularity so it doesn't add to the residue

Comment: You forgot `dz = 3 Pi I Exp[I th] dth`

Comment: Why are right, but adding `* 3 Pi I z` still doesn't give the correct answer

Comment: nevermind. no need for another `3 Pi` there. problem solved!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot the integration measure:

```
With[{z=3 π Exp[I θ]},
    NIntegrate[z^2/(Exp[z]-1)^2 D[z, θ], {θ, 0, 2 π}]
]
```

> 2.27374*10^-13 + 496.1 I

An alternate approach is to just give [`NIntegrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NIntegrate) a contour:

```
NIntegrate[z^2/(Exp[z]-1)^2, {z, 1, 3 π I, -1, -3 π I, 1}]
```

> 1.32365*10^-11 + 496.1 I

Comment: Yap. that solved it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 7):

**Appropriate parametrization** involves $\;dz=\frac{d z(\phi)}{d \phi} d \phi = 3\pi i \exp(i \phi) d \phi$ which has been omitted in the original post. Numeric calculation yields a correct result, while the system can't integrate it symbolically with such a parametrization. Using `Residue` we can find an **exact symbolic result**. In the comments there were some imprecise statements so we demonstrate the full reasoning. 
 There is a beautiful result in complex analysis: [**Residue theorem**](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ResidueTheorem.html) being a simple consequence of the [Cauchy integral theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CauchyIntegralTheorem.html), i.e. for e meromorphic function in a simply connected open subset $U$ of the complex plane we have
$$\int_{\gamma} f(z)dz=2 \pi i \sum_{a \in A} Res_{z=a}(f(z))$$
where $A$ denotes the set of residual points in a region enclosed by $\gamma$.

For the problem at hand: $f(z)=\frac{z^2}{(\exp(z)-1)^2}$  and $\gamma=\{x \in U: |x|=3\pi \}$

Let's find all residual points:

```
A = z/.{ToRules @ Reduce[(Exp[z] - 1)^2 == 0 && Abs[z] <= 3 π , z]} // Flatten
```

> ```
> {0, -2 I π , 2 I π }
> ```

and finally the contour integral is

```
Total[2π I Residue[z^2/(Exp[z] - 1)^2, {z, #}] & /@ A] // Simplify
```

> ```
> 16 I π^3
> ```

With another approach which uses symbolic calculation, *Mathematica 11.2* takes a bit (~10 sec.) to yield a silightly involved expression:

```
int = Integrate[ z^2/(Exp[z] - 1)^2, {z, 3π , 3I π , -3π , -3I π , 3π }];
```

which can be  approximated (simplified) (as observed by Bob Hanlon) with

```
RootApproximant[int/π^3] π^3
```

> ```
>  16 I π^3
> ```

Here we demonstrate different contours of integration we've discussed

```
ContourPlot[{Re[(Exp[z] - 1)^2] == 0, Im[(Exp[z] - 1)^2] == 0, 
             Abs[z] - 3 Pi == 0} /. z -> x + I y // Evaluate,
    {x, -3.5 π, 3.5 π}, {y, -3.5 π, 3.5 π}, 
    Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[ReIm[A]], Dashed, Thick, 
    Purple, Line[{{3π, 0}, {0, 3π}, {-3π, 0}, {0, -3π}, {3π, 0}}]}, 
    PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", Right], 
    ContourStyle -> {{Thick, Darker@Green}, {Thick, Cyan}, {Dashed, Thick, Orange}}]
```

[image]

For various examples of appropriate parametrizations, see e.g.

[Paths integrals in the complex plane](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/36961/paths-integrals-in-the-complex-plane/36962#36962)

[How do I find line integrals?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31017/how-do-i-find-line-integrals/31021#31021)

[How to calculate contour integrals with Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34073/how-to-calculate-contour-integrals-with-mathematica/34090#34090)

There were many different helpful posts on this site, however such an amazing subject as complex analysis deserves repetitions, since [repetitio est mater studiorum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Latin_phrases_(R)).

Comment: +1. Your definition of `A` should include A = `z /. ...` to convert the rules to values. `int` can be simplified with `RootApproximant[int/Pi^3] Pi^3`

Comment: @BobHanlon Thanks, formerly I've written in the notebook something different than in the post.