# Possible bug with contour integration

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex

I wanted to confirm the value of the integral

$$\frac12\int_{\partial\Bbb D}\frac{\sin z}{\cosh z-1}\, dz$$

where $\partial\Bbb D$ is the boundary of the disk of radius $1$. Thus I had written the code

```
Integrate[With[{z = E^(I t)}, (I z Sin[z])/(2 Cosh[z] - 2)], {t, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

what found the wrong result of zero. Using `NIntegrate` instead of `Integrate` it approach the correct answer, what is $2\pi i$. This seems a bug, right? Or Im doing something wrong?

P.S.: I have confirmed the same result on 11.2 and 11.3 versions of Wolfram Mathematica.

---

ACTUALIZATION: this was fixed on version 12.

Comment: Oh, I am deeply sorry. I deleted my post. Now I claim the opposite: Looks buggy to me.

Comment: no problem @Henrik, you are welcome

Comment: What is your version of the system?  Evaluating the above integral it yields `2 I Pi` not zero, at least in _10.3_.

Comment: On my MMA `10.2` gives `2 I Pi`

Comment: This appears to be an issue in `Limit`, or is at least consistent with the fact that `Limit` gets a wrong result for the antiderivative when approaching the origin from the right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The symbolic integral is evaluated correctly:

```
f[t] = Integrate[With[{z = E^(I t)}, (I z Sin[z])/(2 Cosh[z] - 2)], t]
```

> ```
>  1/4 I (-E^(-I E^(I t)) Hypergeometric2F1[-I, 1, 1 - I, E^E^(I t)]
>  + E^(I E^(I t)) Hypergeometric2F1[I, 1, 1 + I, E^E^(I t)]
>  - (1/2 - I/2) E^((1 - I) E^(I t)) Hypergeometric2F1[1, 1 - I, 2 - I, E^E^(I t)]
>  + (1/2 + I/2) E^((1 + I) E^(I t)) Hypergeometric2F1[1, 1 + I, 2 + I, E^E^(I t)]
>  + 2 I Coth[E^(I t)/2] Sin[E^(I t)])
> ```

```
Plot[{Re[f[t]], Im[f[t]]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]

```
f[t] /. {t -> N[2 Pi]}
```

> ```
> -0.446818 + 3.14159 I
> ```

```
f[t] /. {t -> 0.00001}
```

> ```
> -0.446818 - 3.14158 I
> ```

But the symbolic `Limit` of `f[t]` as $t \rightarrow 0^{+}$ is incorrect:

```
Limit[ f[t], t -> 0, Direction -> "FromAbove"]
```

> ```
> 1/8 E^-I ( -2 I Hypergeometric2F1[-I, 1, 1 - I, E]
>            +2 I E^(2 I) Hypergeometric2F1[I, 1, 1 + I, E] 
>            -(1 + I) E Hypergeometric2F1[1, 1 - I, 2 - I, E] 
>            -(1 - I) E^(1 + 2 I) Hypergeometric2F1[1, 1 + I, 2 + I, E] 
>            -4 E^I Coth[1/2] Sin[1])
> ```

```
N[%]
```

> ```
> -0.446818 + 3.14159 I
> ```

Comment: mmm... this seems strange... Using the residue theorem it value must be $2\pi i$, and the graph of the integral doesn't seems to show that it cancels.

Comment: The graph shows that the contour integral is $2 \pi i$, in agreement with the residue theorem.

Comment: Well, You should rather evaluate `Plot[ReIm[f[t]], {t, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Thick, 
 Evaluated -> True, AspectRatio -> Automatic]`

Answer (score 4):

Quite a common problem with symbolic integrals is caused by an arbitrary choice of a complex function branch and in general it cannot be chosen to match any calculation. Therefore such inconsistencies **shouldn't be classified** as bugs. One could find many similar problems on this site. Behind the scene the system encounters the branch cut issue and this can be found in the documentation page of `Hypergeometric2F1`:

> - **Hypergeometric2F1[a,b,c,z] has a branch cut discontinuity in the complex z plane running from 1 to Infinity**.

Namely, calculating the indeterminate  integral (all the following functions are evaluated in version ***10.3***) we obtain the result in terms of the hypergeometric function:

```
f[t_] = Integrate[(I E^(I t) Sin[E^(I t)])/(-2 + 2 Cosh[E^(I t)]), t]
```

> ```
> 1/4 I (-E^(-I E^(I t)) Hypergeometric2F1[-I, 1, 1 - I, E^E^(I t)]
>  + E^(I E^(I t)) Hypergeometric2F1[I, 1, 1 + I, E^E^(I t)]
>  - (1/2 - I/2) E^((1 - I) E^(I t)) Hypergeometric2F1[1, 1 - I, 2 - I, E^E^(I t)]
>  + (1/2 + I/2) E^((1 + I) E^(I t)) Hypergeometric2F1[1, 1 + I, 2 + I, E^E^(I t)] 
>  + 2 I Coth[E^(I t)/2] Sin[E^(I t)])
> ```

and evaluating `f[2Pi] - f[0]` one finds (incorrectly) it is `0`.

```
Plot[ReIm[f[t]], {t, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Thick, Evaluated -> True,
                                   AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

However being aware of the issue we can find the correct value:

```
FullSimplify[ Limit[f[2 Pi - t] - f[0 + t], t -> 0, Direction -> -1]]
```

> ```
>  2 I Pi
> ```

Sometimes *Mathematica* yields incorrect results in specific versions of the system, while it works fine in another versions, see e.g. [Symbolic integration error](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/58940/symbolic-integration-error/58945#58945) where ***ver.  10.0.0*** provided incorrect value, while it has been fixed in newer versions. The problem at hand seems to involve a reverse issue, the newest version provides a wrong value.

By a direct calculation in ***v. 10.3***  I get the **correct result** of the integral:

```
Integrate[(I E^(I t) Sin[E^(I t)])/(-2 + 2 Cosh[E^(I t)]), {t, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

> ```
> 2 I Pi
> ```

This can be also found from the [residue theorem](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/164301/having-problems-integrating-a-function-of-a-complex-variable/164413#164413):

```
Reduce[ Cosh[z] - 1 == 0 && Abs[z] <= 1, z]
```

> ```
> z == 0
> ```

```
int = 2 Pi I Residue[1/2 Sin[z]/(Cosh[z] - 1), {z, 0}]
```

> ```
> 2 I  Pi
> ```

One can find it also using a different contour (using the Cauchy integral theorem), e.g.:

```
FullSimplify[ Integrate[(Sin[z])/(2 Cosh[z] - 2), {z, 1 + I, -1 + I, -1 - I, 1 - I, 1 + I}]]
```

> ```
> 2 I Pi
> ```

It takes more than `1` minute to evaluate because of  a quite involved symbolic result hidden behind `FullSimplify`.

Concluding, this issue is **not a bug**, but rather a common **inappropriate usage** of the computer system.

Comment: Well, there seems to be a bug in calculating the symbolic limit of the hypergeometric function as $z \rightarrow 1^+$ (even though this is on the branch cut); see my answer above.

Comment: No, this is a branch cut issue, evaluate e.g. `f[t] /. {t -> -0.00001}`

Comment: Yes, there is a discontinuity in `f[t]` at $t = 0$. But the limit from above at 0 is still well defined, and is equal to $-0.446818 -\pi i$; Mathematica evaluates this limit symbolically as $-0.446818 + \pi i$.

Comment: It doesn't matter, you misinterpret the result, this is a branch cut problem.

Comment: Compute `N[Limit[f[t], t -> 0, Direction -> "FromAbove"]]`. In 11.3 the answer is wrong.

Comment: I don't have _11.3_ right here, I use _10.3_ and evaluating `Limit[f[2 Pi - t] - f[0 + t], t -> 0, Direction -> -1] // N // Chop` yields correctly `6.28319 I`.

Comment: I have 10.4, and it also evaluates the limit correctly. 11.2 doesn't.

Comment: There have been crucial changes in `Limit` in _11.3_, the OP also claims that `Integrate[With[{z = E^(I t)}, (I z Sin[z])/(2 Cosh[z] - 2)], {t, 0, 2 Pi}]` yields `0` which in `10.3` yields  `2 I Pi`. Therefore it is plausible that there is also something wrong behind `Integrate` in _11.3_